# What is the difference between Sati and Jauhar?

Tags: practice, dharma, women, dharma-shastras

Is Jauhar the same as Sati? If not what is the difference and what is the origin of these terms?

Comment: Sati is name of a very pious and pativrata woman who had a husband named satyavan see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitri_and_Satyavan, and jauhar is I think a hindu-arabic term which evolved in medival times.

Comment: Related http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3594/what-is-the-truth-behind-the-practice-sathi-how-come-this-practice-related-to-h

Comment: Sati was a tradition where a widow gave up her body in the fire after death of her husband. Jauhar is a willing offering of oneself in fire because the invaders used to kidnap the women and used to abuse and treat as slaves, hence they gave up their lives instead of surrendering to demonic invaders.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi isn't sati also voluntary?