# What are the counter-arguments within Hinduism against the Satī (sahamaraṇa) system?

Tags: rituals, practice, dharma, women, smriti

Are there any counter-arguments within Hinduism against the concept/practice of [Satī](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sati_(practice))?

I heard that some commentators/interpreters of scripture believe the widow actually goes to hell since self-immolation is tantamount to suicide.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sati_(practice)#Counter-arguments_within_Hinduism) has very little info. regarding this.

---

P.S. I couldn't find the answer under the more general '*[What is the truth behind the practice of Sati? How is it related to Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3594/2995)*' so asking it as a separate question.

Comment: Are sahagamana and Sahamarana same or different? I haven't heard the word Sahamarana before.

Comment: Yes, sahagamana ("going with") or sahamarana ("dying with") are same. However, [Anumarana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anumarana) and Anugamana appear to be slightly different - these may be referring to Jauhar where the wife assumes the (kshatriya) husband is dead. But people are using these terms interchangeably.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the truth behind the practice of Sati? How is it related to Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3594/what-is-the-truth-behind-the-practice-of-sati-how-is-it-related-to-hinduism)

Answer (score 5):

There are two counter arguments that i found while reading the [Yajnvalkya Smriti.](https://archive.org/details/YajnavalkyaSmritiWithThreeCommentaries)

The commentator Vijnashwera in his famous commentary "Mitaksara" discusses and refutes these two arguments  as follows (go to pp168 of the PDF):

**Objection1:**

> An objection:—The rule of Sati does not apply to Brahmana widows.—But
>   there are texts (says an objector) which prohibit (Anugamana) (satism)
>   for a Brahmani woman, such as :—" There is no anugamana or
>   self-immolation for Brahmani woman ; for this is the command of
>   Brahma. But among the other castes this anugamana is said to be the
>   highest austerity. (Their duty is) to do their husband's good, while
>   he is living ; and to commit suicide when he is dead. But that woman
>   of the Brahmana caste, who follows her dead husband (by anugamana)
>   does not lead either herself or her husband to heaven because of the
>   sin of her suicide.

to which the reply is:

> Reply,—To this we reply that these and several other texts, relate to
>   the ascending of a separate funeral pile, because of this special
>   Smriti : —;" A Brahmana woman cannot follow her husband by ascending a
>   separate funeral pile." From this it follows, that the women of the
>   Ksatriyas and the rest are allowed to ascend a separate funeral pile.

**Objection2:**

> Another objection, -Some, however assert :— ** Because suicide is as
>   much prohibited for women as for men, therefore, this direction for
>   Anugamana (satism), like Syena-sacrifice, is meant for those women
>   (only) who through inordinate love of enjoying heaven, transgress a
>   prohibitory rule of law (which forbids suicide), just as :— " By
>   Syena-sacrifice let him kill his enemies," is a direction for
>   Syena-sacrifice given to those, whose conscience has been overpowered
>   by constant thinking (bhavana) over this doing of injury and by anger
>   (revenge)."

and to which the reply is:

> We say this is wrong. Because it has been described by some that
>   Syena-sacrifice (hawk) is injurious on account of its fruits ; because
>   the conception (bhavana) which is to be accomplished through the
>   instrumentality of the Syena-sacrifice, and whose effect is injury of
>   others, wants the sanction of law (because there is no Vidhi to the
>   effect : —Thou must kill thy enemies :) but (on the contrary) there
>   are prohibition (thou must not injure anybody, not even thy enemies).
>   According to their opinion, because injury (to one's own self here)
>   being a means to attain heaven, is commanded by the law relating
>   scriptures (Sravana) pondering over their meaning (manana), and
>   realizing their sense (nididhyasana) by meditation. Therefore, life
>   should not be cut short, for the sake of obtaining *' heaven," which
>   after all is but temporary, and whose joys are small. This is the
>   meaning. Therefore, for the woman, who wishes not Moksa (emancipation)
>   and is desirous of getting heaven, which is not permanent and of small
>   happiness, Anugamana is proper ; like other Anusthanaa (religious
>   performances) for the attainment of particular desires.
>   **Therefore, nothing is blamable : (both views are correct : suicide for heaven or living for others)**

Comment: Does 'Objection 1' (Sati does not apply to Brahmana widows) apply to [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24403/2995) I asked earlier?

Comment: Yes.. it applies.. @sv.

Comment: "There is no anugamana or self-immolation for Brahmani woman ; for this is the command of Brahma." - where is that command of Brahma written?

Comment: They are quoting some scripture not sure which one..@sv.

Answer (score 4):

Rig Veda does not support the practice of Sati.

> 7 Let these unwidowed dames with noble husbands adorn themselves with
> fragrant balm and unguent. Decked with fair jewels, tearless, free
> from sorrow, first let the dames go up to where he lieth. 8 **Rise, come
> unto the world of life, O woman: come, he is lifeless by whose side
> thou liest.** Wifehood with this thy husband was thy portion, who took
> thy hand and wooed thee as a lover.

**Rig Veda 10.18.7-8**

There are 2 Manu Smriti texts that clearly do not support the practice of sati.

> At her pleasure let her emaciate her body by (living on) pure flowers,
> roots, and fruit; but she must never even mention the name of another
> man after her husband has died.

Manu Smriti 5.157

> A virtuous wife who after the death of her husband constantly remains
> chaste, reaches heaven, though she have no son, just like those chaste
> men.

Manu Smriti 5.160

http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu05.htm

> As in the case of men, **so in that of women also suicide is forbidden.
> As for what Aṅgiras has said—‘they should die after their
> husband’,—this also is not an obligatory act, and so it is not that it
> must be done. Because in connection with it there is an eulogium
> bestowed upon the results proceeding from such suicide. Thus then, the
> performing of the act being possible only for one who is desirous of
> obtaining the said result, the act stands on the same footing as the
> Śyena sacrifice. That is, in connection with the Śyena sacrifice we
> have the Vedic text—‘one may kill living beings by means of the Śyena
> sacrifice,’—and this makes the performance of this sacrifice possible;
> but only for one who has become blinded by extreme hatred; so that
> when the man does perform the act, it does not become regarded as
> ‘Dharma,’ a ‘meritorious act’; exactly in the same manner, when the
> widow happens to have a very strong desire for the results accruing
> from the act of suicide, it is open to her to disobey the prohibition
> of it and kill herself; but in so doing she cannot be regarded as
> acting according to the scriptures. From this it is clear that the act
> of killing herself after her husband is clearly forbidden for the
> woman. Further, in view of the distinct Vedic text—‘one shall not die
> before the span of his life is run out’—being contradicted by the
> Smṛti-text of Aṅgiras, this latter is open to bring assumed to have
> some other meaning.** Just as in the case of the Smṛti rule ‘one should
> take the final bath after having read the Veda’,—the injunction of the
> bath, as pertaining to one who has not yet studied the meaning of the
> Vedic texts, has been taken as having a different meaning.

**Commentary of Medhatithi on Manu Smriti 5.157**

Comment: Verse 5.157 in your answer is actually 5.155 in [Medhātithi’s commentary](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200541.html).

Comment: The Bengali book numbers the shloka as 5.157. I checked another English translation of Manu Smriti and it also numbers the shloka as 5.157. So I don't know why there is this discrepancy.

Comment: Check the Manu Smriti text given here http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu05.htm