# Under what conditions, a women is not allowed to perform Sati?

Tags: scripture, sati

[This answer on Sati](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35290/661) lists the conditions in which a woman is not allowed to Sati.

> Only a Pativrata alone can enter the pyre upon the death of her
> husband. That too, **if she has young children, or she is pregnant, or
> she is menstruating**, even a Pativrata too cannot undergo Sati.

It says three conditions:

1. Woman with pregnancy
2. Woman with young children and
3. Women undergoing menstrual cycle.

The answer did not mention the exact verses saying this.

Which scriptures tell that woman is not allowed to perform Sati under the aforementioned conditions?  What happens if she performs Sati under those prohibited conditions?

Answer (score 4):

[Narada purana](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/naradapurana%20home.html) is one of the scripture that enumerates those conditions under which a woman is not allowed to perform Sati. The conditions include woman with infant children, pregnant woman, woman whose monthly course has not been started and women undergoing menstrual cycle.

The following excerpt by Aurva contains all the details regarding that

> Aurva said :   ‘“O chaste lady ! O beloved wife of the excellent king
> ! Please do not proceed ahead with this risky venture. An emperor,
> verily the slayer of enemies, stays within your womb. O blessed
> princess !
>
> **The following (ladies) do not ascend a funeral pyre, viz. those with
> infant children (depending on them), pregnant women, those whose
> monthly course has not yet started, and women in the menses.** Means for
> expiation for Brahmana-slaughter and other sins have been mentioned by
> excellent men; **but there is no expiation for an imposter, a person who
> slanders, and killing a child in embryonic stage**.O observer of good
> vows ! There is no atonement for an atheist, an ungrateful fellow, a
> person indifferent to dharma and a treacherous fellow. Hence, O
> splendid lady ! It does not behove you to commit this great sin. The
> misery that has befallen you shall subside completely.”
>
> [[51-55, Chapter 7: The Glory of the Ganga, Narada Purana]](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.12945/page/n156/mode/1up)

Along with the conditions under which a woman should not perform Sati, the passage also discusses about the consequences if she ascends to funeral pyre under those conditions. She is said to be committed the grave sin for which no expiation has been mentioned in scriptures. She will undergoe the [punishments mentioned in this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15908/661).