# What is the male equivalent of a Widow called, in the scriptures?

Tags: dharma, women, dharma-shastras, men, widow

As I understand, a female (having lost her husband), is called as a Widow (hindi: विधवा, vidhavā ).

Scriptures have detailed guidelines on the "Code of Conduct - CoC" for the Widows: [Which scriptures deal with rules for widows?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16296/which-scriptures-deal-with-rules-for-widows).

I'd like to know, **What's the parallel 'male equivalent' for the widow, called in the scriptures ?**

Moreover, **Does Hinduism have any similar "Code of Conduct", for the 'male equivalent' too?**

If Yes, Please give details about those CoC. If No, I'd like to know the possible reasons (present in the scriptures or commented on, by eminent personalities) for the non-existence of any CoC for males?

Answer (score 12):

Vidhura is the word used for a widower in [Baudhayana Dharma Sutras 2.10.17.4](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/baudhayana-dharmasutra/d/doc116431.html):

> 1. Now we will explain the rule for entering the order of ascetics (saṃnyāsa).
> 2. Some (teachers say), 'He who has finished his studentship may become an ascetic immediately on (the completion of) that.'
> 3. But (according to others, asceticism is befitting) for Sālīnas and Yāyāvaras who are childless;
> 4. Or a **widower** (may become an ascetic).

A footnote on 4 says the following:

> Vidhura, translated, according to Govinda's explanation, by 'widower,'
> perhaps includes all persons who have been separated from their
> families.

According to [Sanskrit dictionary](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/index.php?mode=3&direct=au&script=hk&tran_input=widower) the corresponding Sanskrit words for widower are Vidhura and amena.

> विधुर     m.  vidhura     widower 
>      अमेन   m.  amena       widower

The rest of the question can be answered as follows:

> Does Hinduism have any similar "Code of Conduct", for the 'male
> equivalent' too?

No. The situations are not the same. Because men can have multiple wives but women can't have multiple husbands. For example: [What is the explanation for Aitareya Brahmana III. 3](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45628/what-is-the-explanation-for-aitareya-brahmana-iii-3)

And, for widows, remarriage is not an option as per scriptures:

> Manu 9.65. In the sacred texts which refer to marriage the appointment
> (of widows) is nowhere mentioned, nor is the re-marriage of widows
> prescribed in the rules concerning marriage

Whereas, a young (twice born) widower must marry if he wants to keep the sacred fire because Vedic rites can't be performed without the wife.

> A Homa should never be performed by the 'Ritwik and others in the
> absence of the married couple. What is done in their absence becomes
> profitless, (1)
>
> By leaving aside the Sacred Fire and transgressing the limit, if a
> person goes away with his wife and the time for Homa expires, he shall
> have to deposit the Fire again. (2)
>
> If the Sacred Fire is mixed up with the fire that destroys a forest,
> one should preserve it. And when that fire is extinguished, he should
> again consecrate it. (3) If one having many wives goes on superseding
> the eldest one, some wish that the Fire should be consecrated again.
> But this is not [the view of] Gotama, (4)
>
> Having cremated a becoming wife, dead before, with the fire of the
> vessel, **one should get himself re-married without delay [and
> consecrate the Fire again]**.
>
> *Katyayana Smriti, Chapter 20*

Comment: "a young (twice born) widower must marry if he wants to keep the sacred fire..."— instead of **young**, *debt-free* would be more appropriate, IMO. A debt-free [of the 3 debts] widower can better turn an ascetic as per Bouddhayana.

Comment: He has to maintain the sacred fire. That's why he should marry again. He might have cleared the debts already @BasedShaiva