# Are there any proofs for followed sati pratha in any scripture

Tags: scripture, practice

In previous days there was something called sati pratha, as per my assumption which is not followed in the current time.

As per Hinduism We give respect everything in this universe, So why we followed such a wrong concept. Was it portrayed in a wrong way?

Comment: You can see my answer here : http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15395/4732

Comment: Scriptures have praised the practice..But its entirely the decision of the widow..Sati custom can't be forced upon her as a rule..There r no such rules in fact..

Comment: @Rickross I have read it but, the translation can be wrongly translated. is there a any famous incident which can be related to this.

Comment: @Mongrel Your question is already answered there. I think you should edit it to make it different.

Comment: @Mongrel Still your question is duplicate of that question. Both questions ask about nature of "Sati".