# Is entering into funeral pyre (chita pravesh) a dharmic way of suicide?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, puranas, manu-smriti

Agni's another name is pavak (i.e which purifies everything)
So, Is burning oneself alive by entering into funeral pyre (chita pravesh) a dharmic way of committing suicide ?

Arjun took a vow of entering into his funeral pyre if he was not able to kill Jayadrath before sunset . Thus it indicates that it is a valid way of committing suicide.

It is different fact that most men  don't have the guts to do it . But Is it dharmic way of committing suicide ?

Comment: [Sati - Yes](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3594/what-is-the-truth-behind-the-practice-of-sati-how-is-it-related-to-hinduism). There have also been other instance of people doing Agni Pravesh in Itihasa/Puranas - e.g. Amba/Shikhandi.